# Setup Amazon account on Intellij

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2

I would like to setup mu Amazon account on Intellij AWS plugin.
I want to be able to access S3 and EC2.
I have the [Intellij AWS plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4558?pr=) installed, but I can't figure out how to login with my Amazon credentials.

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sacg2.png) (image below), I can **choose** an account, but I can't figure out where to set it up.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open Settings dialog (File->Settings).
2. In AWS->Accounts section create a new account and enter account number, access key ID and secret access key. (You can get them in your AWS account profile)
3. Press "Test Connection" button to verify that your settings are correct.
4. Press "Apply" after you are finished.